# supervisor restart stratgy and childspec

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, erlang-supervisor

I am reading rabbitmq's `supervisor2.erl,rabbit_channel_sup_sup.erl, rabbit_channel_sup.erl` source code.

When `childspec`'s start parameter is `"temporary"`, it means the child won't be restarted after any reason of exit. Is it right?

When start parameter is `"temporary"`, there is no difference for every restart parameter, `one-for-one, one-for-all,one-for-rest,simple-one-for-one`. Because the code running result is same. Is it right?

The following code is from `supervisor2.erl` file

```
do_restart({permanent = RestartType, Delay}, Reason, Child, State) ->
    do_restart_delay({RestartType, Delay}, Reason, Child, State);
do_restart(permanent, Reason, Child, State) ->
    report_error(child_terminated, Reason, Child, State#state.name),
    restart(Child, State);
do_restart(Type, normal, Child, State) ->
    del_child_and_maybe_shutdown(Type, Child, State);
do_restart({RestartType, Delay}, {shutdown, restart} = Reason, Child, State)
  when RestartType =:= transient orelse RestartType =:= intrinsic ->
    do_restart_delay({RestartType, Delay}, Reason, Child, State);
do_restart(Type, {shutdown, _}, Child, State) ->
    del_child_and_maybe_shutdown(Type, Child, State);
do_restart(Type, shutdown, Child = #child{child_type = supervisor}, State) ->
    del_child_and_maybe_shutdown(Type, Child, State);
do_restart({RestartType, Delay}, Reason, Child, State)
  when RestartType =:= transient orelse RestartType =:= intrinsic ->
    do_restart_delay({RestartType, Delay}, Reason, Child, State);
do_restart(Type, Reason, Child, State) when Type =:= transient orelse
                                            Type =:= intrinsic ->
    report_error(child_terminated, Reason, Child, State#state.name),
    restart(Child, State);
do_restart(temporary, Reason, Child, State) ->  %%<<----attention here, just report_error,not calling restart child function
    report_error(child_terminated, Reason, Child, State#state.name),
    NState = state_del_child(Child, State),
    {ok, NState}.
```

Answer (score 1):

A temporary child is never restarted, that's true. But the restart strategies still play a role in determining  supervisor behavior - the all-for-one strategy will kill all children (which won't restart because they are temporary) while the one_for_one won't kill any other children.  Basically these restart strategies tell the supervisor what to do with the *other* processes (the others being the ones that didn't die), so there is a difference.

Comment: I have copied more code above and add one remark above. Because not calling "restart function",and the strategies of one-for-one, one-for-rest have no chance to take effect. Is it right?

Comment: I think this code just deals with process that died. I am *assuming* that there must be other code that makes a decision on what to do with the other child processes. But I may definitely be wrong here...